# Итератор, который будет брать за основу другой итератор и возвращать каждый k-й элемент из коллекции

Tags: java, итераторы

учу сейчас итераторы, и у меня есть 2 задания которые никак не могу понять как сделать.
Реализуйте итератор, который будет брать за основу другой итератор и возвращать каждый k-й
элемент из коллекции.
2. Реализовать в качестве итератора генератор чисел Фиббоначи (два первых числа 1 и 1,
каждое следующее число является суммой двух предыдущих чисел): 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11 и т. д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот по первому заданию я думал делать это как то так, но во первых это не работает почему-то, во вторых в задании сказано использовать другой итератор в качестве основы, то-есть надо использовать 2 итератора.
Вроде как задания лёгкие, но всё равно не получается...
Буду очень благодарен за ответ

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите код. Без него не получается.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, код я вставил, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется,что тут подход неправильный. Я бы имплементировал итератор и переопределял его методы, чтобы получить кастомную реализацию для подобных заданий:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class CustomIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final Iterator<T> iterator;

    private final int step;
    
    private boolean isFirstelement;

    public CustomIterator(Iterable<T> itrb, int step) {
        this.iterator = itrb.iterator();
        this.step = step;
        this.isFirstelement = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        int count = 1;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (isFirstelement) {
                isFirstelement = false;
                return true;
            }            
            if (count==step) return true;
            iterator.next();                    
            count++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return iterator.next();
    }

}
```

Ну и используем как-то так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    Iterator iterator = new CustomIterator(list, 2);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```